# MonetDBLite - problems installing package

Tags: r, monetdb, monetdblite

I've been trying to run this script:

https://github.com/ajdamico/asdfree/blob/master/Pesquisa%20Nacional%20por%20Amostra%20de%20Domicilios/download%20all%20microdata.R

But on this line

```
install.packages( c( "MonetDBLite" , "survey" , "SAScii" , "descr" , "downloader" , "digest" , "stringr" , "R.utils" ) )
```

I get the following message:

```
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: 
‘MonetDBLite’ These will not be installed
```

I have very basic code knowledge and couldn't find a fix for this on the web.

Can any1 help, please?

Comment: Which platform is this? Can you post the output of `sessionInfo()` please?

Comment: Hello. Here's the output

R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

Comment: strange that you are not getting the binary package from CRAN... Brazilian Windows, Anthony, any ideas?

Comment: I tried a couple of different CRAN mirrors too.

Can't I install it from source? Does MonetDBlite run on 32 bit?

Comment: @RobertoDumke could you try with 64 bit R ?  thanks

Comment: You can install from source if you have Rtools installed I think. And yes it runs on 32 bits but this does not make too much sense. But you could try to manually install from the binary zip file (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/MonetDBLite_0.3.1.zip)